# Take value from input field using Jquery and assign it to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have small input field with button. It looks similar like this:
[image]
**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="my_input"><span class="btn">Save</span>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
        // send data to $_POST['#my_input']
    });
```

If user press "save", can i use jquery to assign PHP isset ?

```
    if(isset($_POST['#my_input'])){
      //action
    }
```

Comment: no. jquery cannot "assign" anything in PHP. but you **CAN** have jquery perform a regular http form submission (either directly or via ajax), which would cause the browser and PHP to create key=value pairs in _GET/_POST for you.

Comment: Can you give me some tutorials or some code where i can learn that from? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `post` or `ajax`-method of jQuery to submit your form-data asynchronous:

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
    var input = $('#my_input').val();
    $.post('url/to/file.php', {data: input });
);
```

In your php-file you can access the data like:

```
if(isset($_POST['data'])){
    //action
}
```

**Reference**

[$.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: Can i do that on same page? I mean not using any additional php files? Is that possible? Thanks

Comment: Yes you can do it. just define a form and submit button . form without action . and on bottom the php code  what i gave. no jquery is required

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in following manner:-

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      $('.btn').click(function(){
        $textboxval = $('#my_input').val();
         $.ajax({
            url: 'page.php', // page name where you want to get value of that textbox
            type: 'POST',
            data : {'my_input':$textboxval},
            success: function(res) {
               // if you want that php send some return output here
                }
          });
    });
});
</script>
```

And on page.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['my_input'])){
   echo $_POST['my_input'] ;
}
```

Note:- if you want to return to ajax back then you need to write return rather than echo and then you can get the value in your success response.